# Prefetch optimization of tf.data doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am working with the *tf.data API* and am analyzing the various speed-ups obtained with optimizations written [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).
I'm working with the tf.data API and I'm analyzing the various speed-ups obtained with the optimizations written in, but in all cases what I've noticed is that you don't optimize performance using the prefetch option.
It almost seems that no optimization is implemented and therefore there is no overlapping between CPU and GPU.
Currently I'm using TF 2.11.0 but I've used also TF 2.10.0 and TF 2.8.3 and the fact remains the same.
I tried also with different batch size.
I have used also different PC with different GPUs but the fact remains the same.
I worked with Cifar10 in which each image is RGB 32x32 and this training-set is made by 40.000 images.
A dummy code that I've used is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import time

def get_model_data_augmentation_CPU():
    """Return the Keras model for data-augmentation on CPU"""
    # Define Keras Model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.1),
      layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.1),
      layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.2),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dropout(0.3),
      layers.Dense(10)
    ])
    adam_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer = adam_opt,
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode='horizontal'),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
])

model = get_model_data_augmentation_CPU()

BATCH_SIZE = 32 
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)) 
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(lambda x,y : (data_augmentation(x),y), num_parallel_calls=3) 
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset_train = dataset_train.prefetch(1) # If I comment this line the perfomance remain the same


start_time = time.time()
history = model.fit(
    dataset_train,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
)
end_time = time.time()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use dataset_train.prefetch(tf.data AUTOTUNE) ?

Comment: Yes, of course I've also tried with tf.data.AUTOTUNE option but doesn't change anything.
For example, when you have worked with tf.data API have you ever achieved a speed-up using prefetch function?

Answer (score 1):

I created a notebook and tested on this dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/data

I ran the notebook 3 times with prefetch and 3 times without prefetch and here are the results:
With prefetch, training time: 43.15s, 44.12s, 43.53s
Withoud prefetch, training time: 45.97s, 46.62s, 45.95s
**That is basically 5.6% of improvement. Not too bad.**

I think in your case there weren't much improvement because all your dataset are already in you ram and to process that didn't take much time, so there were basically no difference.

Here is the code (it's based on yours) if you want to try it out:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import time

def get_model():
    """Return the Keras model for data-augmentation on CPU"""
    # Define Keras Model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.1),
      layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.1),
      layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      layers.Dropout(0.2),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dropout(0.3),
      layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])
    return model

from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory
data_dir = "catdogs"
train_dataset = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(128,128),
    batch_size=32,
    subset="training", #subset="both", lo nuevo
    shuffle=True,
    validation_split=0.1,
) 
val_dataset = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(128,128),
    batch_size=32,
    subset="validation", 
    shuffle=False,
    validation_split=0.1,
) 
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
    layers.RandomFlip(mode='horizontal'),
    layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
])
model = keras.Sequential([
    data_augmentation,
    get_model()
])
adam_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer = adam_opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

start_time = time.time()
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=val_dataset
)
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Total time: {end_time - start_time:.2f}")
```